# Grease Pencil stroke thickness not behaving in render like in viewport

Tags: grease-pencil

I have a weird behaviour with GP stroke thickness. I managed to get a consistent line thickness on a scaling up house I made — thanks to some keyframes on the GP object (Thickness scale and its layers' individual Stroke Thickness).

Very happy with the animated viewport look.

Problem is when I render a video, the scaling thickness is ignored. The weirdest is that it seems to render with the thickness from the frame I'm on in the viewport.

Meaning that depending on where I am on the timeline, I'll get different renders.

Any idea what could be the problem ?

viewport preview : https://gyazo.com/46e87ad00c4e2b5ed75789b07fbfec80

rendered animation : https://gyazo.com/81fd1ce37efbd954618a1ee369c3e95c

Blend file : https://gofile.io/?c=SFQO49

Using 2.82 daily build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks again from the help of the Blender Discord server users, I've been told that the "Adjustments > Stroke Thickness" does not render.

I managed to get the look I want using the "Strokes > Thickness Scale" setting only.

edit : This bug is now solved with the latest 2.82 build.

Comment: Note that I opened a Bug here : https://developer.blender.org/T71909 with a simple .blend file